# I'm tyring to remove a line from a file

Tags: ruby, file-io, readline

Is something wrong with my code?

```
line = File.readlines("file.txt").sample(1)[0]
puts line

def remove_lines(fname, line)
    IO.write(fname, IO.read(fname).gsub(/^#{line}\n/, '')) 
end

remove_lines("file.txt", "#{line}")
```

I've tried adding an "a" after the filename in readlines..tried an "rb" and an "r+". I'm just trying to get it to read one line from `file.txt` and then remove the same line being read. Please help?

Comment: `line` will have a `\n` at the end. So you will only succeed in `remove_lines` if the next line is empty (i.e. you have `\n\n`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) (`line.strip`) to strip out the leading and trailing whitespace characters (if any) from the `line`. Also, remove `\n` from the `gsub`:

```
def remove_lines(fname, line)
   IO.write(fname, IO.read(fname).gsub(/^#{line.strip}/, '')) 
end
```

That will do the trick and your code will work as expected.

Comment: i used `inspect` and saw quotes but no `\n` . regardless i used your .strip method in the brackets and the item stll hasn't been removed.

Comment: Really? its removing the line fine for me. Can you give me the text file you are trying on?

Comment: It depends on the contents of the text file. Please show us the contents of the text file so that we can help.

Comment: its literally just one word `theerealoshae` in `file.txt`

Comment: try this: `IO.write(fname, IO.read(fname).gsub(/^#{line.strip}/, '')) `

Comment: there's no space, no line after the word in the file either.